# Firebase keyword is deprecated

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am newbie to Firebase. Firebase keyword is deprecated.So what are the changes that firebase made? Where to get updated tutorials.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 18 May 2016  Firebase changed to include several new products: Analytics, Storage, Remote Config, Crash Reporting, Dynamic Links, and Notifications.

Now you can find all info here.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Here the new API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/packages